# What is the best way of generating a lot of instances of a class in Dart performance-wise?

Tags: dart

All in the title. I'm looking for the best performance possible when creating a lot of instances (~100 000).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on details. This is an optimization question, and optimizations always depend on the details, because those details determine which changes can be done without affecting the final result.

Top of the list: Don't do it. Takes zero extra space! If you can represent the information in some other way than an object instance (a single integer would be awesome!) then consider doing that. (Such an integer could be a pointer into a large string or byte array which holds the actual data in a shared and optimized way. Whether that makes sense depends on what the data are.)

Second: Don't do all of them if you don't need to. If any of the objects are equivalent, reuse those instead of creating new objects. That's effectively caching, which means it can keep those objects alive longer than necessary if you don't actively try to avoid it, and if the majority of objects are actually new, the cache might take up more space than the rest of the objects would. That depends on the next item...

Third: Make the class *small*, which means as few fields as possible. Avoid anything that isn't necessary, or which can be computed when needed (unless it's definitely going to be needed and is expensive to compute, the usual trade-offs).

Fourth: Share any substructure which can (and likely will) be shared among multiple objects. That's a variant of items 2 and 3 applied to sub-components.
Don't do:

```dart
class MyClass {
  int left;
  int top;
  int right;
  int bottom;
}
```

if

```dart
class MyClass {
 Point _topLeft;
 Point _bottomRight;
 int get left => _topLeft.x;
 int get top => _topLeft.y;
 int get right => _bottomRight.x;
 int get bottom => _bottomRight.y;
}
```

would allow you to share the same `topLeft` point or `bottomRight` among *multiple* instances, even if all the `MyClass` instances have unique combinations. Again, depends on the sharing percentage, size of the extra objects, and the cost of caching, which depends on the underlying data.

Other than that, just do it. Creating 100K objects doesn't sound *that* bad if the objects themselves are simple. If each contains, say, a large JSON object and a 1K string, you may want to consider other options.